# how check the parent to update the children in the same table?

Tags: mysql, database

[image: consider this mysql table]

the full_id field is a string shows the "parents tree".

example :name1 is a parent of name2 and name4 is the parent of name6,  and name2 is the parent of name4 etc..
We should not have any children or grand children active=1 if the parent at any level  is active=0.
Example of the wrong rows : 6 and 8.
How can I check for the wrong active values?

Comment: This problem would be _much_ easier if, instead of storing the hierarchy as a dot-separated string, you stored the direct parent of each id in a separate column.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, but I am in a stage where this table been around for a while, and I need to find a way to sort this problem without touching the table structure

Comment: You could join using a `LIKE` condition on the `full_id` column, but the problem is that you don't know how many joins to perform because the hierarchy could have an arbitrary height.

Comment: yes this is the issue :)

Comment: Can we assume a maximum depth to the hierarchy?  If not, then I am pretty sure you will need dynamic SQL for this.

Comment: there is no maximum maximum limit, but currently the longest chain has got 11 ID.

Comment: I would abandon this schema. It is like dismounting a tiger. At some point you have to get off. And hopefully you can climb a thin tree fast.

Comment: I know, the thing is there is no option for now. the table is already in use , the table has many other fields, the screenshot tis only an example.